# OpenShift Process parameters issues

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We are deploying our service to OpenShift using YAML file,

Our YAML file contains lot of dynamic variables that we pass to OC Process command and Parameters.

We are able to deploy by processing the yaml, but when the parameters are having space issues or when more than once space is provided between parameters the OC Process command fails,

what is the standard procedure to prevent this ?

```
oc process templatename routepath= "abc.com" tagname= "v1:laest" hostname= "xyz.com" imagename="employeedetails" cpu="100m" memory="150mi"
```

the above command contains space in parameters, how could we prevent these kind of issues ?

Comment: What happens if you specify parameters with -p option? oc command help said that `-p, --param=[]: Specify a key-value pair (eg. -p FOO=BAR) to set/override a parameter value in the template.`

Comment: its the same when specifying -p ,   it shows error "template name must be specified only once", my question is about how to prevent these issues like space,

Answer (score 0):

The space after the equals in your examples (e.g `routepath= "abc.com"`) is invalid syntax. A value such as `routepath="abc.com"` is valid and interpreted as a parameter. The example of `routepath= "abc.com"` is not valid due to the space between the equals and the value, and seems to be interpreted as another YAML file by `oc process`.

If you want the space included in the value then it needs to be `routepath=" abc.com"`, i.e the quote starts immediately after the equals, and the space is within the quote.

Comment: yes, correct, I am looking for a standard way to prevent these kind of errors. Sometime these can be overlooked. Is there a better way to do this.